# Cómo llamar a una widget de tkinter múltiples veces

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nueva en esto y estoy haciendo un programa para subir documentos masivamente a una web. El primer botón que hice con tk inter es para preguntar al usuario qué tipo de documento quiere subir. Lo que quiero hacer ahora es lanzar nuevamente esa ventana cuando termine de subirse UN tipo de documento, para darle al usuario la posibilidad de subir OTRO tipo. Aclaro que recién empecé a programar; hasta hace unos meses estaba estudiando Contabilidad. =/
Este es mi código:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
class OpcionTipoDeDocumento:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.iconbitmap("bigpython.ico")
        master.minsize(280,150)
        master.geometry("280x150")
        master.title("DOCUMENT TYPE")

        self.label = Label(master, text="SELECT THE DOCUMENT TYPE")
        self.label.pack()

        self.tipo1_button = Button(master, text="Tipo1", command=self.opcion_tipo1)
        self.tipo1_button.pack()

        self.tipo2_button = Button(master, text="Tipo2", command=self.opcion_tipo2)
        self.tipo2_button.pack()
    def funciontipo1(self):
        def subirtipo1():
            "cosas para subir tipo1"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        root.destroy()    
        time.sleep(1)
        subirtipo1()
        "ACÁ DEBERÍA APARECER LA WIDGET NUEVAMENTE"
    def funciontipo2(self):
        def subirtipo1():
            "cosas para subir tipo2"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        root.destroy()    
        time.sleep(1)
        subirtipo2()
        "ACÁ DEBERÍA APARECER LA WIDGET NUEVAMENTE"
root = Tk()
my_gui = OpcionTipoDeDocumento(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Cuando finaliza una de las funciones por tipo de documento, quiero que aparezca nuevamente la widget. Pero no tengo idea de cómo llamarla.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres conseguir, pero acá te dejo un par de formas para seleccionar archivos.
En el primer caso, los eliges uno a uno, y en el segundo, tienes el contenido de un directorio completo, luego tendrías que filtrar por algún valor.
"""
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, filedialog
from os import scandir, getcwd

class OpcionTipoDeDocumento:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.minsize(280,150)
        master.geometry("280x150")
        master.title("DOCUMENT TYPE")
        self.master = master
        self.archivos = []
        boton1 = Button(self.master, text="Buscar archivos 1", command=self.obtenerArchivos).place(x=0, y=0)
        boton2 = Button(self.master, text="Buscar archivos 2", command=self.obtenerArchivosPorCarpeta).place(x=0, y=30)



    def obtenerArchivos(self):
        self.archivos = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "/",
                                   title = "Seleccione un archivo",
                                   filetypes = (("Archivos twx", "*.png"),
                                                ("Archivos zip", "*.xml"),
                                                ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")
                                                ))
        print(self.archivos)

    def obtenerArchivosPorCarpeta(self):
        self.archivos = [arch.name for arch in scandir("C:") if arch.is_file()]
        print(self.archivos)

root = Tk()
my_gui = OpcionTipoDeDocumento(root)
root.mainloop()
```